# html scroll/size doesn't work correctly. IE7 at least

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

This is an issue not easy to explain, basically, when you open my site (http://www.securebitcr.com/test/sbcr/) and resize, you can see an **"extra"** space at the end of the site, is there a way to limit that?

It is like, if I have a div(height:800) but the window itself is sized to 400px, I am able to see the rest of the site, but all the other objects that I'm attaching to the bottom (like the footer) ... you can see all the code at once in my file.

http://www.securebitcr.com/test/sbcr/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this in any other browser, so you may have to serve these changes to just IE7, by using a stylesheet just for IE7, via a conditional comment.

Set these styles:

- `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }`
- `body { position: relative }`

I recommend trying those changes, and seeing if they're fine to apply for all browsers - that might well be the case.

Comment: @ ElbertF 
Thanks Guys, the SET option works but, one thing that I want is a moving footer!, so, if I resize the window keep seeing the footer (mountains).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `#content_frame` is causing the scrollbar to appear even though you're using `overflow: hidden` on the parents. I'm guessing `position: relative` has something to with it, try removing that. It works fine in IE8 and Firefox.